# ngRepeat:dupes Error when entering nulls in array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

### How do I enter successive nulls in a javascript array?

I am having trouble understanding how to enter successive null values in a JS array. This is my working script:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.items[0] = [,,"this doesn't work"];
  $scope.items[0] = [null,"this works"]; 
  $scope.items[1] = [null,,"this works"];
  $scope.items[2] = [null,null,"this doesn't work"];
  $scope.items[3] = [null,,,"this doesn't work"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in items">
        <td ng-repeat="column in row">{{column}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add your script here. Not via an external link.

Comment: Paste your fiddle as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: @basic Added script in revision

Comment: Is it an issue with angular outputting it??

Comment: @epascarello Yes, it remains blank in the rows that don't work.

Comment: `$scope.items[2]` is how you would "enter successive nulls in a javascript [sic] array".

Comment: @Klaycon Added snippet in revision

Comment: Notice how every example that works *has no repeats* and every example that doesn't work repeats null or undefined. See the linked dupe target for info on resolving. Problem is incorrect use of `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @Klaycon Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Problem appears to be with how you are outtputting the values in your angular ng-repeat. Alter the code to use track by to deal with duplicated values.

```
<tr ng-repeat="tr in items">
    <td ng-repeat="td in tr track by $index">{{td}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion, thank you.